# iPhone 5s has 5+ Gb of free memory space but refuses to take photos saying "Storage is full"; reboot works for a while

Tags: iphone, photos, memory

I have an iPhone 5s (16 Gb). It currently has 5.6 Gb of free memory space, but refuses to take photos, saying "Storage is full". When I reboot it, it does take photos for a while, but then again this "Storage is full" menu starts popping up. I've deleted all I could, there's now a truckload of free space, but the problem hasn't gone away.

I even installed iTunes and made sure that indeed I have a lot of free memory. The iTunes software offers to install a new OS version, but again says that "You need 770 Mb of memory, and you don't have it" - yet it itself indicates that I do have more than 5 Gb.

What do I do?

Screenshot of storage use from iTunes:

[image]

Screenshot of storage use from the phone itself:

[image]

Comment: Have you got a screenshot of the storage use?

Comment: I've just added the screenshot to my post. It's in Russian but it says **Free: 5.70 Gb**

Comment: I wonder if there is free space being taken up by temp and cache files... ? Perhaps if you backed up the phone, wiped and then restored it (which clears unneeded files) that might do the trick.

Comment: @SteveChambers Facebook itself is taking a lot of storage. I don't use the app but this is huge! Also for OP, my iPhone stops syncing photos after 15.5/16 GB and since your phone says even 750 mb is not available, both photos and update are in agreement about space. You should consider cleaning it.